# Stored procedure not appearing in client side [WCF Dataservice and EF4.0]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

We are using Visual Studio 2010, and .Net Framework 4.0. The project settings "Target Framework" is ".Net Framework 4.0". I added the "Stored Procedure" to the server side as suggested by this [link](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/checking-out-one-of-the-new-stored-procedure-features-in-ef4/). But in the client side, the stored procedure method is not appearing.

This is the method generated in the DataModel.Designer.cs file.

```
/// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
public ObjectResult<global::System.String> display()
{
    return base.ExecuteFunction<global::System.String>("display");
}
```

I updated the client side, still this method is not appearing. I tried with entity datatype also.

Comment: What do you mean by "client side"?? If you have your stored procedure in SQL Server, and you followed all the step in that linked blog post, you should have that new method on your EntityContext object.

Comment: Well, i done all the things as suggested and i tried in the client side "where the service reference is created" and i tried to access though context object. But it should be accessed from the "server side", means where the sql is been interacted. This stored procedure can be called by "server side" and which can be implemented in [WebGet] method and from "client side", this can be accessed though framing URI along with Execute method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your server / client side correctly, this sounds like a permissions issue.
SQL access is always run at the server.

Comment: Yes Dave, you are correct. "SQL access is always run at the server"